# Performance Monitoring on Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, network-monitoring, munin

I have a server that is running on **django-nginx-gunicorn**. I wish to monitor it's performance and get to know which module is using more resources, performance of the network etc.

I tried using [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), which is pretty famous, but I couldn't get it to work with Django. So it'd be great of someone could help me setting up Munin on my Django-based server or suggest a similar alternate that can easily be incorporated with Django.

Comment: Do you want to monitor the network/hardware (which is what munin is famous for), or do you want to measure your _application_ statistics? Its not clear.

Comment: The network/hardware. Application status is not an issue (nginx logs)

Comment: Okay, so now you want to have a django application as a front end to your munin installation for a friendlier interface? Munin comes with its own interface, so I'm not sure what you mean "work with django". By the way, nginx will not show you the application status. It doesn't know, for example "how many users are online".

Comment: Yeah, *a django application as a front end to munin installation for a friendlier interface*. That is what I need. Basically, everything that munin does. I'll get the application stats later somehow. (Actually, I'm a newbie to both Django and Munin and I want to get munin to work, but I'm utterly confused.)

Comment: I'm curious why you are putting django in the mix, there are [many templates for munin](https://www.google.com/search?q=munin+templates) if you just need a friendly face.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Okay, so do you mean to say, installing munin has no relation with the web framework whatsoever?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid found something that solved my issue. https://github.com/ccnmtl/django-munin And yes, you were right! What I needed an interface, that's it! Munin was running all the time :/